# News resources for GIS community?

Tags: references

I currently rely on a mixture of mailing lists, twitter and a couple of blogs.

What do you use for your GIS media intake, and why?

Comment: I voted to close this topic because it is asking for value judgement and cannot be answered definitively.  At the very least, it should be a community wiki.

Comment: I second Community Wiki.

Comment: true, very true, and I did not noticed it before.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[Slashgeo](http://slashgeo.org/) ceased publication as of June 2, 2015, but apparently continues to share items [on Twitter](https://twitter.com/slashgeo).

Answer (score 9):

Don't forget the [GIS Stackexchange](http://gis.stackexchange.com)!

Answer (score 5):

Adding to few mentioned already:

- [GIS and Science](https://gisandscience.com/)
- [ESRI Mapping Centre blog](https://www.esri.com/about/newsroom/overview/?rmedium=NewsFallback&rsource=blogs.esri.com/Support/blogs/mappingcenter/)
- [Strange Maps blog](https://bigthink.com/strange-maps/)
- [digitalurban](https://www.digitalurban.org/)

Might be also worth browsing through RSS feeds of couple of journals. My favourites:

- [Journal of Geographical Systems](http://www.springerlink.com/content/103079/?p=ce496b612f854d3790493518fb5e6922&pi=0)
- [International Journal of Geographical Information Science](http://prod.informaworld.com/smpp/title%7Edb=all%7Econtent=t713599799)
- [Computers, Environment and Urban Systems](https://www.sciencedirect.com/journal/computers-environment-and-urban-systems)
- [Cartography and Geographic Information Science](https://web.archive.org/web/20130510022639/http://www.ingentaconnect.com/content/cagis/cagis)

Answer (score 4):

I heavily check on a few good blogs to be inside the scoop.

- [James Fee](http://www.spatiallyadjusted.com/)
- [Dave Bouwman](http://blog.davebouwman.com/)
- [Regina Obe's](http://www.bostongis.com/blog/)

Answer (score 4):

Very nice also the Planet OSGeo: http://planet.osgeo.org/

> Planet OSGeo is a window into the world, work and lives of OSGeo
>   members, hackers and contributors.

Answer (score 2):

1. Lots of information in [GIS Lounge](http://gislounge.com).
2. [Very spatial](http://veryspatial.com)
3. Since I am working with ArcGIS products, I read [ESRI blogs](http://blogs.esri.com).
4. All news and fun things about Google products can be found in [Google Maps Mania](http://googlemapsmania.blogspot.com).
5. Free tools: http://freegeographytools.com

Answer (score 0):

My favourites:

[Gretchen Peterson blog](http://www.gretchenpeterson.com/blog/) (Cartography)

[The Map Room: A Weblog About Maps](http://www.maproomblog.com/)

[Don Boyes blog](http://donboyes.com/) (Teaching GIS)

[TeachSpatial](http://www.teachspatial.org/) (resources for spatial teaching and learning)

[Mapperz](http://mapperz.blogspot.com) (The Map & GIS News finding blog)

[My GIS Career](http://mygiscareer.com.host01.cfdynamics.com/)

[Esri UK blog](http://geoxchange.esriuk.com/)

<s>[GISi blog](http://blog.gisinc.com/)</s> (403 - Forbidden Error)

[Safe Software blog](http://blog.safe.com/) (FME)

[ArcGIS Team Python blog](http://arcpy.wordpress.com/)

Answer (score -1):

I like the [podcasts from directions magazine](http://www.directionsmag.com/podcasts/). I can't really tell how small (or big) they are as a company. I'm from Germany, they don't sell the magazine here.

The podcast is in dialog mode between two editors, and they usually talk about a lot of products, technologies, trends. I liked how they compared their predictions for a calendar-year with the actual results after that year has ended.

Answer (score -1):

I use Feedly, which I believe was the successor of Google Reader, when it ceased to exist. However, I liked Google Reader better, as it was easier to save the read material in different categories.